# Enable reputation tooltip for close voters

Tags: feature-request, closed-questions

It already works for comments, that the reputation is shown as a tooltip when you hover over the user link of the commentator.
It can't be be a big deal to enable it for users that voted to close a question.

Please implement it!

**EDIT**

I want this to get an impression about the people who voted to close...

Comment: Why do you want this?